# Facebook Graph API - search event with coordinates

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm busy with an app and I use Facebook's Graph API for that. I am trying to search Events with this url: https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=Party&type=event&center=54,2&distance=100&access_token=%@.
When I load the results, I get some Events, but they're not even close to the given coordinates.

Does anyone know if I am using the right URL or is there a better one?

Thanks,

Jelle

Answer (score 0):

I think center and distance are used for type=place, not for type=event.

Comment: I am afraid you're right. Do you know if it's possible to get a list of events and maybe filter that with a city name?

Comment: Yes you can get a list of events.  Just use that query you have in your question. `search?q=Party&type=event`

Comment: Do you know if it's also possible to use a city instead of a query?